# Adding images to project under specific location for injected javascripts(GWT)

Tags: javascript, java, image, gwt, console

Probably i do not know how to find the proper suport resource for this problem.

Problem is that i am reciving error in browser console and of course image is not loaded.

[image]
Situation: In form are injected .js script what uses defined images `ScriptInjector.fromString(textResource.getText()).setWindow(ScriptInjector.TOP_WINDOW).inject();`

and in .js preview :

```
 var slider = OpenLayers.Util.createAlphaImageDiv(id,
                   centered.add(-1, zoomsToEnd * this.zoomStopHeight), 
                   new OpenLayers.Size(20,9), 
                   imgLocation+"slider.png",
                   "absolute");
```

where imgLocation is

```
        var imgLocation = OpenLayers.Util.getImagesLocation();
```

And in that Util

```
 /**
 * Property: ImgPath
 * {String} Default is ''.
 */
OpenLayers.ImgPath = '';

/** 
 * Function: getImagesLocation
 * 
 * Returns:
 * {String} The fully formatted image location string
 */
OpenLayers.Util.getImagesLocation = function() {
    return OpenLayers.ImgPath || (OpenLayers._getScriptLocation() + "img/");
};
```

in runtime function getImagesLocation  are returning "img/"

For info this variable "OpenLayers.ImgPath" i can set in some native init method but dont know what img src location need.

In project physically images are added. 
[image]

But they are not added/loaded into webpage.

[image]

Main question how i can correctly add theese img for escaping theese errors ? 
I have all Java 1.8, GWT, js posibilities.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Move all these images into `/war/img/` folder in your project, and redeploy your app.